# zero result from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am getting zero result from my query. Here is the source code

```
$sql = "SELECT rate_to FROM `s_currencies` WHERE sign='$'";

    $course= mysql_fetch_row($sql);

    $variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$course;
```

The query works just fine when I run it from phpmyadmin, but returns 0 in PHP. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are not accessing the returned row correctly

Use $course[0] ,where the array index matches the fields selected from left to right

use `var_dump/print_r` the `$course` variable to see if it is actually returning nothing, or if its just your access usage that is causing the problem.

Comment: ...and presumably use `$course['rate_to']` instead of `$course` for the calculation. `echo "'$'"` seems to echo the dollar sign without escaping just fine btw.

Comment: wouldnt it be $course[0] since he is using just fetch_row, and not fetch_assoc?

Comment: Ah, yes, been a while since I used the mysql_* versions :)

Comment: Sorry nothing had changed

Comment: hmm i always thought it was replaced... must be because he is using the wrong syntax for the row.

Comment: @BogdanOnyshenko Did you try the `$variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$course[0];`?

Comment: have you tried echoing out mysql_error() to see if it returns an error?

Comment: @BogdanOnyshenko i think $variant['price'] value is equal to zero . echoing $variant['price'] before calculation will help u

Comment: Problem is I can't do eny echoing since because I am using Simpla Cms. Var_dump shows NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$variant['price'] = 1;    
$variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$course[0];
```

Comment: Sorry. Still getting 0.

Comment: Check the @Goutam Pal answer  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT rate_to FROM `s_currencies` WHERE sign='$'");

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT rate_to FROM `s_currencies` WHERE sign='$'";

$course= mysql_fetch_row($sql);
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT rate_to FROM `s_currencies` WHERE sign='$'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$course= mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

You have missed the mysql_query

also

```
$variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$course;
```

should be

```
$variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$course[0];
```

Comment: @Bogdan Onyshenko  what is the value of $variant['price']? is it 0?

Comment: No it is not 0. There must be 2 and before I tried to use query it was working

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved Here is the code sorry it looks like mess but works and thank you all for pations!

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT rate_to FROM s_currencies WHERE id=1 LIMIT 0, 30 ");
  $course= mysql_fetch_row($sql);
//$rate=$course[0];
  $variant_price = $variant['price']*$course[0];
  $variant['price']=$variant_price;
 //$variant['price'] = $variant['price']*$rate;
```